# How could Hive use Daisy's blood?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

At one point in Season 3, Hive engages a scientist to try to re-create the Kree experiment that turned humans into inhumans.  Their first attempt fails, and it's explained that it didn't work because they needed the blood of a living Kree, not a dead one.

Later, Daisy says they can use her blood, because she was injected with the drug GH.325, which was made from Kree blood.

But wasn't the source of GH.325 a Kree that was dead?  We saw the corpse a few times.  So how does Daisy's blood have "blood from a living Kree"?  And if it works because it is mixed with living blood, couldn't they have done that with anyone, using the dead Kree blood they already have?

Comment: I suspect it involves some technobabble about Daisy, being a living person, thus has "living" blood.

Comment: @Tim I pre-addressed that point in my last sentence: If that were the case, why is Daisy such a big deal?  Someone refers to her as the "Golden Goose" at one point.  Not to mention Hive went to some trouble to try and get living Kree blood through other means before Daisy brings up her blood; if it's enough to mix the dead Kree blood with living blood why bother with the whole space-beacon plan when you could just inject one of your minions?

Comment: I think the whole point of kree blood is that it kills normal humans. Daisy was the daughter of an inhuman and a mad scientist - she's probably one of a very small number of people that could be injected and survive.  So maybe they did try to inject a minion and he exploded, or something.

Comment: @Tim I think you're simply mistaken that kree blood kills normal humans - Coulson and others survived it just fine and were in fact healed by it.

Comment: @MartianInvader Daisy's blood could be a big deal because the Kree-introduced mutation is much more pronounced, possibly evidenced by the magnitude of what she has been able to do with her powers. Possible cause or another factor is that she is a descendant of a relatively "pure" line of Inhumans, since her mother and presumable her ancestors as well have been living and breeding within Inhuman community not mixing with "normal" humans(except her father).

Comment: Daisy's inhumanity just means she doesn't start "writing" like the humans did when injected with GH325.